# Case Activity does't respect 'Do not notify assignees for'?

Tags: civicase, activities

When submitting activity from case, assignee contact still gets email even though the activity type is included in 'Do not notify assignees for' setting under Display Preference. However it obeys the setting when sent from Activity form. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not intentional but it's come up before. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1582 and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1649

UPDATE:
@pradeep-nayak submitted a PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16800 so it will restrict for case activities too in version 5.25.

Comment: Have submitted PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16800

Comment: Can you add the PR link to your answer so that i can accept as answered?

Comment: Done. Thanks for the PR!